# Can self-intersecting tolopolgies always be Transcended by Going up a Dimension?

Tags: general-topology, low-dimensional-topology

Apologies if my language is imprecise or poor, I'm not mathematically educated, simply a curious learner.

Working from the comments, I have edited my question for language and specificity.

I'm interested in topologies which self-intersect in n dimension.  Do all such topologies *not* self-interect in n+1 dimension? If so, how do we know it's always true?  Is there a name for this phenomenon? What happens to an n dimensional self-intersection at n-1 dimensions?

Like if I have a klein bottle which I'm viewing in three dimensions, and I added a second identical neck alongside the first one, thereby creating new self intersection points (where the two necks diverge from each other and then merge back into the bottle) these self-intersections would not occur in the fourth dimension.  If this is correct, is there any way to get an intuitive picture of why it is the case? What would happen to them in the second dimension?

Comment: Can you give an example of what you think this might look like? It's hard to know what you mean.

Comment: @EthanDlugie sure, I will edit my question to add it.  Thanks!

Comment: The use of the term _topology_ in the question doesn't sound like conventional mathematics, but perhaps you're trying to get at something like the fact that an intersection of two lines in a plane cannot be removed by jiggling the lines slightly, but in three-space the intersection can be removed by moving either line an arbitrarily small distance?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes, that sounds on the right track.  I'm just going to try to edit the question a bit and give an example.  I'm more interested in the difference between three and four dimensions because I can't get an intuitive sense of how it works yet.

Comment: Briefly, passing from $n$-dimensional space to $(n+1)$-dimensional space in the sense of the question "works the same way for all $n$." For instance, the $(x,y)$-plane and $z$-axis meet in a point and the intersection cannot be removed by moving either by a small amount. "Lifting" either along a fourth coordinate, however, immediately removes the intersection.

Answer (score 2):

You may be looking for "The Whitney Embedding Theorem", which says that an $m$-dimensional smooth manifold can always be embedded in a $2m$-dimensional space, and that $2m$ is the best possible result. So your Klein bottle, which is a surface, so, a $2$-dimensional manifold, can be embedded in $4$-space, but not in any smaller dimension. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedding#Differential_topology and/or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem

Comment: Ahh, right.  So the klein bottle can only be 'immersed' in 3-space and 'imersions' by definition self-intersect?  How do I know if my weird two-necked klein bottle is still a smooth manifold?

Comment: Immersions aren't required to self-intersect, they just aren't forbidden to self-intersect. I'm not sure I understand your description of a two-necked Klein bottle. Surely it is a surface, a two-dimensional manifold, embeddable in ${\bf R}^4$, but smoothness is a finer concept. E.g., a sphere and the surface of a cube are the same as surfaces, but only the sphere is a smooth realization of that surface; the cube has sharp corners and edges. There are textbooks and websites where you can read up on these things and get better answers than I can give.

Comment: Many thanks for clarifying about immersions. Sounds like I need to do some learning about smoothness!